# Last git changes on a given file

Tags: python, gitpython

Using the [`gitpython`](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) library, I'm trying access the date of the last changes on a given file. So far I only found out how to:

```py
import git
# get a handle on a repo object for the current directory
repo=git.Repo()
# get a handle on the tree object of the repo on the current branch
tree=repo.active_branch.commit.tree
# get a handle of the blob object of a given file
blob=tree['path/to/a/file.py']
```

After that I got stuck...

Comment: Why would you want to look at the blob object at all? Look at the history, working back through the commits until you find one that touches the file. (Granted, this is more interesting when you have a commit with multiple parents -- then you need to decide what kind of value you mean by "newer")

Comment: Because it seems natural to think about it as a property of the file. The git command I would use for it take the file as an argument (`git log -1 --pretty="format:%ci" /path/to/file.any`). All git GUI or IDE integration would easily give me the last modified date of a file or even of a line.

Comment: Sure, but GUIs and IDE integrations are porcelain; as someone using git-python, you're expected to be working with the plumbing layer, not the porcelain. (There's even sound design argument for this separation of concerns: not doing things behind the back of / on behalf of people writing new porcelain -- as you are -- ensures that the people doing that work understand the actual implementation of the operations they request, and thus the performance characteristics and, more generally, cost of those operations).